# My Own Impressions on AdMob?

Tags: ios, admob, currency, impressions

I successfully made an app and its waiting for review right now. But meanwhile i've been playing the game on my mom's phone because, one, i dont have an iphone and its for iphone, and two, I actually like playing it. But I looked at my admob because i wanted to make sure i wasnt messing with it by playing my own app but it turns out i have 100 impressions! D: No clicks though, and i know im not supposed to click on my own ads. What do the impressions do? what are they? Am I going to get in trouble? I stopped playing the game now.

btw my moms iphone no longer has my developer Apple ID signed in on it, but it can still play the app and the UDID is still registered with the developer account if that matters.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to add some quick code that differentiates between you and every other user.  "If username == 'MobileGamer', don't display ads" and such.  Just to be safe.  I haven't used AdMob, but ad companies are famously strict with this sort of thing.  Better not to risk it.

Comment: @Nerrolken You should put that in an answer, is a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to worry about.

Impressions are when an ad is displayed.
Requests are when an ad is requested.
Clicks is when you clicked on an ad (you haven't done that so nothing to worry about).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to add some quick code that differentiates between you and every other user. "If username == 'MobileGamer', don't display ads", or something similar. Just to be safe.

For example, I have several websites where both the ads and the stats-tracking code is omitted if I'm the logged-in user.  That way, Google can't claim that I'm trying to steal money from them when I'm using my own website (they've tried before), and my user stats aren't skewed by huge activity spikes whenever I'm adding features or testing.

I haven't used AdMob specifically, but ad companies are famously strict with this sort of thing. I was once kicked from an advertising plan simply because my roommate, who was on the same network as me, clicked on an ad no my website *once*.

Better not to risk it. Just don't show the ads at all, for you or your testers.